# How to escape slashes in LIKE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to do some clean-up in a database and change some urls from http://www.domain1.com to http://www.domain2.com, so I am doing a query like this:

```
UPDATE mytable set url = REPLACE(url, '"http://www.domain1.com"', '"http://www.domain2.com"')
```

the double comma is needed as this strings are part of a JSON string

however, the problem is that in the DB the old url is for some reason escaped so I have something like this

```
http:\/\/www.domain1.com
```

if I run a query like these they don't match anything

```
select * from mytable where url like '%http://www.domain1.com%'
select * from mytable where url like '%http:\/\/www.domain1.com%'
```

and therefore the replace query doesn't work either, so what's the correct way to escape these strings?

Comment: I don't *think* you need to escape slashes in MySQL. backslashes (`\\`) yes, but not slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try:

```
where url like '%http:\\/\\/www.domain1.com%'
```

To be honest, I don't understand how or why *forward* slashes would be escaped.  Perhaps you are better off just using a wildcard:

```
where url like '%http:_/_/www.domain1.com%'
```

Comment: this does not work unfortunately. anyway yes I don't need to escape them that's why I need to do some clean-up.

Comment: sorry this works actually, it didn't work in my SequelPro query panel. thank you.